# each_with_index is outputting the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application that calls the helper method in the view by:

```
 <%= link_to_receipts @purchase_request %>
```

in the helper I have:

```
link_to_receipts purchaserequest
   purchaserequest.receipts.each_with_index do |receipt,i|
     #some code here commented out...
   end
end
```

but it outputs the array like so on the view:

> > [#>tagged_by: "joe somebody", purchase_request_id: 39, created_at: "2011-08-22 20:39:18",updated_at: "2011-08-22 20:39:18">]

If I comment out the each_with_index it will not show the array, but if it is there it will.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  In the helper method I had the variable html first initialized in the block like so:

```
link_to_receipts purchaserequest
    purchaserequest.receipts.each_with_index do |receipt,i|
     html = ""
     #more code here
    end
 end
```

When it should have been declared outside of the block:

```
link_to_receipts purchaserequest
html = ""
    purchaserequest.receipts.each_with_index do |receipt,i|
     #code here
    end
 end
```